# for if else loop - fill values in column based on matching columns from separate dataframes

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have two dataframes.

```
df1

ID  Name   
A1  Dave
B2  Bob
C1  Sheila   
D1  Tim   


df2

ID   Focal
A1      0
B1      0
C1      0
D1      0
E1      0
F1      0
```

I want to fill in the "Focal" column with 1's if values in df1$ID match df2$ID.

I've tried looping it with:

```
for (i in 1:length(df2)){
  if (df1$ID[i] == df2$ID[i]){df2$Focal[i] = 1}
  else {df2$Focal[i] = 0}
}
```

but get error saying levels sets of factors are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `%in%`

```
df2$Focal <- as.integer(df2$ID %in% df1$ID)
```